# how to compact Msaccess database using c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

is it possible to compact the  Msaccess database using c# if so let me know the way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
public static void CompactAndRepair(string accessFile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application app)
        {
            string tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(accessFile),
                              Path.GetRandomFileName() + Path.GetExtension(accessFile));

            app.CompactRepair(accessFile, tempFile, false);
            app.Visible = false;

            FileInfo temp = new FileInfo(tempFile);
            temp.CopyTo(accessFile, true);
            temp.Delete();
        }
```

See also [Use the CompactRepair method of the Application object to compact and repair the database](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Access/UsetheCompactRepairmethodoftheApplicationobjecttocompactandrepairthedatabase.htm)

Comment: I wonder if adding a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application to your app might bind it a specific version of office.  The Code Project solution below will use dynamic binding to avoid this.

Comment: Hi, This way delete the data of one of my tables..  do you have any idea why that happen?

Answer (score 5):

```
...
//invoke a CompactDatabase method of a JRO object
//pass Parameters array
objJRO.GetType().InvokeMember("CompactDatabase",
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    null,
    objJRO,
    oParams);
...
```

See more details at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mdbcompact_latebind.aspx

Answer (score 1):

i used the article at:
[Compact and Repair an Access Database Programmatically Using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18081/Compact-and-Repair-an-Access-Database-Programmatic?msg=4715572#xx4715572xx)

i modified it a bit to make it simpler to use:

```
public static bool CompactAndRepairAccessDB(string source, string destination)
{
    try
    {
        JetEngine engine = (JetEngine)HttpContext.Current.Server.CreateObject("JRO.JetEngine");
        engine.CompactDatabase(string.Format("Data Source={0};Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;", source),
            string.Format("Data Source={0};Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;", destination));
        File.Copy(destination, source, true);
        File.Delete(destination);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

dont forget:
Right Click Reference in the Solution Explorer -> Add Reference -> COM -> search 'jet' -> Add 'Microsoft Jet and Replication Objects...'

and also add:

```
using System.IO;
using JRO;
```