# Microsoft Access Compact and Repair using C# .accdb files

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, jet

I need to Compact and Repair .accdb (last MS Access) version using C#

I tried using this:

```
var jroEngine = new JRO.JetEngineClass();

var old_ = Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='c:\a.accdb';
var new_ = Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='c:\b.accdb';

jroEngine.CompactDatabase(old_, new_);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(jroEngine);
```

There is an error:

> {"Invalid argument."}

Comment: What are the types of old_ and new_?  I think they only need to contain the paths 'c:\a.accdb', etc.  In any case, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866421/how-to-compact-msaccess-database-using-c-sharp for an example.

Comment: I have tried with only the paths and didn't work, it should be correct.. I think it is the version or something like that :/

Comment: see the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7775/Compact-and-Repair-Access-Database-using-C-and-lat) the process better described here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7775/Compact-and-Repair-Access-Database-using-C-and-lat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the most straightforward way to do it:

```cs
string sourceDbSpec = @"C:\Users\Public\a.accdb";
string destinationDbSpec = @"C:\Users\Public\b.accdb";

// Required COM reference for project:
// Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
var dbe = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine();
try
{
    dbe.CompactDatabase(sourceDbSpec, destinationDbSpec);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Your code does the same as my version. However I couldn't make it work properly, I think it should work with older versions of MS Access.

Comment: Yes, I still haven't got the solution for this case.